# Update a single document in mongodb using spark with java

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, bigdata

I just started apache-spark with java. There is many documents saved in a collection I want to find a document on the basis of some key and update it.
Simply I want to do find and update in apache-spark with java

This is the code to read a document form mongo

```
Map<String, String> readOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
readOverrides.put("collection", "bb_playing22");
ReadConfig readConfig = ReadConfig.create(createJavaSparkContext()).withOptions(readOverrides);
JavaMongoRDD<Document> customRdd = MongoSpark.load(createJavaSparkContext(), readConfig);
        JavaRDD<Document> rdd = customRdd.filter(((t1) -> {
            return t1.getLong("playing22_id") == 3; //To change body of generated lambdas, choose Tools | Templates.
        }));
```

but not able to update this document

Answer (score 0):

Spark does a lazy evaluation of your transformations hence unless you call an action over an rdd, it won't execute any transformations you code.
See common actions [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions).

Also, this does not seem like a use case where you'd like to use spark.
If your actual requirement is just to update a document as per a value then you should look into indexing in mongo and just update a document through a mongo driver in java directly.